# Right click context menu for <div> like anchor (open new tab etc..)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, anchor, contextmenu

Due to usability reasons I shouldn't use a div wrapped with anchor tag.

So I created a card shaped new div. And direct user to destination with jquery.

My only problem is when I right click to this div, it doesn't show a context menu like anchor tag does(open in a new tab ext..).

I'm wondering if is there a way to add a context menu to a div that looks like it is an anchor?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event

Comment: Why don't you want to wrap a `div` with an `anchor`? [If the `div` does not have additional links (or other interactive content) inside it, wrapping it is fine according to the HTML5 specification.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

Comment: According to usability rules link text shouldn't exceed 80 characters. And my client has almost 4000 of them. So they don't want to manually fix it. They are all on template level so fixing that will be a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add functionality like given?

```
document.addEventListener( "contextmenu", function(e) {
    // functionality to perform
  });
```